# android dialog activity position

Tags: android, dialog, android-activity

I created an non-maximized activity using android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" to make it looks like a dialog. I need to change the position of the activity on screen but I didn't find how to do this...

Answer (score 24):

To change the position (with the theme set to `Theme.Dialog`), you can override the gravity, size and coordinates of the LayoutParams of your activity's decor view after it has been attached to the window. Here's an example:

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();

    View view = getWindow().getDecorView();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
    lp.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
    lp.x = 10;
    lp.y = 10;
    lp.width = 300;
    lp.height = 300;
    getWindowManager().updateViewLayout(view, lp);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a custom theme with `Theme.Dialog` as its parent:

```
  <style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

So, for each item in the Dialog theme that you want to change, use `CustomDialogTheme` instead of `Theme.Dialog` inside the Android Manifest. See [the android developper docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Use  .setGravity()

progDialog = ProgressDialog.show();

progDialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);

Answer (score 0):

For bottom:

Keep this in your activity.

```
@Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        try {
            View view = getWindow().getDecorView();
            WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
            getWindowManager().updateViewLayout(view, layoutParams);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Note: You can change your gravity by setting this  Gravity.BOTTOM (TOP, LEFT, RIGHT)