# Align an activity as dialog on top left

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, alignment

i know this question was asked for aligning a dialog on the left, 
but here i'm using an activity with a

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` and the problem is that it's display at the center of the screen and i want to display on the top left corner.

is there any way to do so ?

i have tried using the `android:layout_gravity="top|left"` on my concerned activity .xml but that doesn't work.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you tried the solution given by Joe on this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163427/android-dialog-activity-position ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this on your onCreate of dialog activity

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = getWindow().getAttributes();

        wmlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: it worked, it's not perfectly aligned as there's still a margin but i'll work on it. Thanks !

Comment: how can i set little margin from left as it is shown extreme left is little conjusted?