# Setting layout parameters globally

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

Is there a way to define a default position on the screen of dialogs in my Android application, eg. in the manifest or as a global theme? I want a solution similar to  [android dialog activity position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163427/android-dialog-activity-position) 
or [Changing position of the Dialog on screen android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467026/changing-position-of-the-dialog-on-screen-android) but without having to set the position of each dialog individually.

Comment: If you provide your code or snippet ..then we can help you better

Answer (score 0):

Why not just to create your own ActivityBase in your app prepare your own default version of dialog implementation and reuse that activity wherever you want ..Even more you can override that method.